# Can I cancel a university offer acceptance in Canada?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, canada

I just received an offer from an Ontario university for a post-graduate program and it requires me to reply very soon. However, I also have a professor at another university who is very likely to give me an opportunity to do research for him as a master's student. I really want to do research with that professor, but the "likely" doesn't mean a guarantee, and it also doesn't mean the offer from the other university is going to arrive before the decision deadline. Could I accept the offer first, then, if the other university accepts me, cancel that same acceptance even after the decision deadline? There is no funding or scholarship involved. It is just an offer with a decision date.

Comment: Though the linked question involves Europe, the answer in this case doesn't really depend on that.

Comment: The linked question involved contracted money exchange, so I don't think it applies to my situation

Comment: What about this https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/183646/university-admission-offer and this https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41105/rejecting-a-phd-offer-after-having-accepted-it-advice ?