# Can I decline a PhD offer after I told the department I accepted? (choice between University of Alberta and Concordia)

Tags: phd

For Concordia Univ, the professor there helped me a lot. He helped me improve my statement of purpose and also recommended me to the committee. In Feb, I was told that I was accepted with a $150k scholarship for 4 years! I waited for a week and accepted the offer.

However! 3 hours later, the professor from the Univ. of Alberta sent me an email. He told me the department was considering recruiting me and providing fellowship. He liked to have an interview with me.

How can I deal with this situation? Actually, Alberta's ranking is high and the professor's research interest is totally aligned with mine. But I don't want to be a dishonest person to decline the offer from Concordia.(the scholarship is also generous)

Could you please tell me which I should choose?

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/183646/university-admission-offer, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193805/retracting-acceptance-offer-to-graduate-school, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41105/rejecting-a-phd-offer-after-having-accepted-it-advice, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187056/can-i-cancel-a-university-offer-acceptance-in-canada

Comment: Any sane person would prefer to live in Montreal over Deadmonton.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That does not necessarily guarantee that the PhD program in Concordia will be more suitable than the one in Edmonton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can decline.  I would advise not doing so until you have an offer from another place in writing and confirmed (an interview is not an offer).

I would recommend finding out the timeline for the other place.

In terms of which offer you should take, assuming you have 2, that's not something I can tell you. You should consider both the professional and personal aspects of both.

Professional: supervisor, supervising team, research fit, resources, reputation, etc.  Also consider work-life balance, expectations, income opportunities, scholarship, duration, research support (conference and travel funds, research funds for consumables etc.).  Look at what the funding gets you (duration, extensions, leave, amount, and what you have to do for it)

Personal: Look at the place you would have to live, cost of living, how much you'd be paid, hobbies, family, friends, whether you like the town (or think you would) etc.